# Best way to determine if a string will throw an Out of Memory Exception

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services, testing, out-of-memory

I have a web service that returns a massive amount of XML to the client. Depending on some clients they have so much data being returned the XML is unworkable on the client side, and results in Out of Memory exceptions when anything tries to accesses it.

Part of our solution to address this problem is allowing the client to provide a date range to reduce the amount of data returned. Even if we constrain the date range to, say 1 or 2 years, there is the possibility over time that the data will still be too large to work with.

What i would like to do. Instead of returning the data to them that will cause an exception on their end, i would like to test it on the web service and if it fails i would send a response back saying to reduce their date range.

What is the most efficient way to trigger an Out of Memory exception that proves the data is to large to be workable. but wont add much more overhead and time, when the string would pass.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think it's impossible to know. It all depend on the available block size of memory. Do your user really need to see that much data? An option would be to only send what is needed and lazy load everything. If they want to see 2 years of data, maybe they only want a summary by month and then drill down on specific month. Also, XML contains a lot of "useless" tag information that could be reduce by sending a csv.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an older legacy application. thankfully only a couple the clients are having problems due to their size. Most clients wont be affected. I am limeted by only being able to change the amount of data returned. (getting permission to do this was difficult enough)  changing the format of the XML file is not possible.